# long chef run fails with Connection reset by peer - recvfrom(2)

Tags: ssh, chef-infra

BUT, doesn't fail when running the same recipe in debug mode.

Chef 12.11.18

After troubleshooting this issue quite some time now, I think the root cause of the problem is my ssh configuration.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks,
Liora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my ISV.